# SQL - SET DEFAULT doesn't work when deleting a value

Tags: sql, postgresql, default

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE REP
(
      PRIMARY KEY REP_NUM CHAR(2) DEFAULT ('00'),
      LAST_NAME CHAR(15),
      FIRST_NAME CHAR(15),
      STREET CHAR(15),
      CITY CHAR(15),
      PROVINCE CHAR(3),
      ZIP CHAR(5),
      COMMISSION DECIMAL(7,2),
      RATE DECIMAL(3,2) 
);
```

And:

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_NUM CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (REP_NUM) REFERENCES REP ON DELETE SET DEFAULT,
    CUSTOMER_NAME CHAR(35) NOT NULL,
    STREET CHAR(15),
    CITY CHAR(15),
    PROVINCE CHAR(3),
    ZIP CHAR(5),
    BALANCE DECIMAL(8,2),
    CREDIT_LIMIT DECIMAL(8,2),
    REP_NUM CHAR(2) 
);
```

As you can see, the `REP_NUM` column is the primary key in the `REP` table and a foreign key in the `CUSTOMER` table.

For example, if I enter new values into the `REP` table with the value of `REP_NUM` being 35, and also insert new values to the `CUSTOMER` table with `REP_NUM` being 35, and then I delete it from the `REP` table:

```
DELETE FROM REP WHERE REP_NUM = '35';
```

I want the `REP_NUM` value in the `CUSTOMER` table (foreign key) to now be 00.

However, when I run this code, it doesn't work. Instead of getting '00', when I delete '35', I just get a "blank value" in the `REP_NUM` attribute of the `CUSTOMER` table.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't see any default value set In customer table though. Moreover, I think a trigger is best choice in this scenario.

Comment: Do i need to set a default value in that table too? i tried and it gave me an error..
And it's for assignment for one of my courses, we still haven't covered triggers so i guess using it isn't expected of us

Comment: `SET DEFAULT` says to use the default value *for those columns*, not to use the default for the *referenced* columns, in some other table.

Comment: I was trying to put this in the customer table:
FOREIGN KEY (REP_NUM) DEFAULT ('00') REFERENCES REP ON DELETE SET DEFAULT,

and got a syntax error..

Comment: @Gambit2007: you need to put the `DEFAULT('00')` where you define the **column** `REP_NUM` - not where you define the foreign key!

Comment: Unrelated but: you most certainly do **not** want to use `char`. Use `varchar` instead. Also which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @marc_s i tried.. look at my comment that's above yours.. for some reason it didn't work..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i'm using Postgres

Comment: @Gambit2007: yes - it didn't work because you added the `DEFAULT('00')` to the **FOREIGN KEY** definition - ***NOT*** the actual column definition. Try using `REP_NUM CHAR(2) DEFAULT('00')` at the very end of your table creation script.

Comment: @marc_s i tried putting DEFAULT('00') at the actual column definition as well, as you can see in the code that's on my original post.
However, instead of setting the value to '00' upon deletion, it just sets it to blank for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues:
REP-table:

- a default for a primary key doesn't make sense, it will fail the 2nd
  time you use it

CUSTOMER-table

- You don't have a default on REP_NUM, your main problem in this topic
- Your foreign key references table REP, but on what column?

Both tables:

- A CHAR() field using the abbreviation "number" doesn't make sense.
  CHAR(2) is also very limited in the amount of options.

This one works:

```
CREATE TABLE REP
(
      REP_NUM CHAR(2) PRIMARY KEY -- No default, doesn't make sence, it will FAIL the 2nd time you use it.
    -- other columns
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(
    CUSTOMER_NUM CHAR(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    FOREIGN KEY (REP_NUM) REFERENCES REP(REP_NUM) ON DELETE SET DEFAULT, -- mention the column as well!
    REP_NUM CHAR(2) DEFAULT '00'
    -- other columns
);

INSERT INTO rep(rep_num) VALUES('00');
INSERT INTO rep(rep_num) VALUES('35');

INSERT INTO customer(CUSTOMER_NUM, rep_num) VALUES('x', default); -- results in 'a'
INSERT INTO customer(CUSTOMER_NUM, rep_num) VALUES('y', '35');

DELETE FROM rep WHERE rep_num = '35';
```